# Bootstrap 3 column has weird space inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display 2 images inside a row and column. I don't want any top/bottom spaces inside column. How do I do that?

```css
img {
 vertical-align: top!important; 
}
.col-md-6 {
 border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/13x11/">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/77x12/" style="margin: 0 0 0 7px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The column has 26px height but should have just 12px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the unwanted spacing, you can add `line-height: 0;` to your div, like so:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" style="line-height: 0">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/13x11/">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/77x12/" style="margin: 0 0 0 7px">
</div>
```

You can find an explanation for this behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952703/4742088).

Comment: sorry, I'm talking about top/bottom spaces. If you run the example you can see there's a big space after the images

Answer (score 0):

That's beacause of the default `line-height` which is approx. 20px + 2px for the border